# Подсвечивание эллементов

Tags: css

Подскажите как с помощью CSS сделать так, что бы подсвечивались кнопки, картинки... после наведения на них указателя? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вам нужен псевдо-класс `:hover`

Comment: Это только для ссылок, а как например сделать так:
Одно фото потимней, другое посветлей и когда я навожу мышку на вото, автоматически активируется фото посветлей и кажется будто бы оно подсветилось. Может что-то не правильно понимаю, только учусь.

Comment: В современных браузерах свойство hover поддерживается для любых элементов. В IE6 не поддерживается(кроме ссылок). Так что можно использовать.

Comment: Да, точно. Спасибо.

Comment: Одно фото потемней, другое посветлей. Использовать две фотки нецелесообразно, лучше закрыть фото дивом c черным фоном и менять его прозрачность с помощью hover.

Comment: а где можно посмотреть пример кода - как закрыть дивом, или что бы одна картинка сменяла другую...

Answer (score 3):

Используйте псевдо-класс :hover. Он работает не только для ссылок, а для всех элементов. Исключением является только IE, где hover срабатывает только для ссылок. Но и это можно обойти, используя display:block для ссылок, в которые и вставлять нужный контент.

Также почитайте про события в javascript - onmouseover, onmouseout и аналогичные.